# HTTP 404 on “sudo apt-get update”

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt, http-status-code-404

I am using Linux Mint. When I try to update packages using the command `sudo apt-get update`, I get this problem:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: May be your Network is blocking, to download some of the required files. Use Proxy or VPN to download them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `trusly` distro but there is a `trusty` ("Trusty Tahr", aka Ubuntu 14.04)(and `http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/trusty` is a valid URL). And AFAIK there is no Ubuntu distribution called "rafaela" (the "r" distro is "Raring Ringtail" aka Ubuntu 13.04).

So, check your URLs.

Comment: i  change it to trusty , but i still get this error

Comment: `W: Conflicting distribution: http://download.virtualbox.org rafaela InRelease (expected rafaela but got trusty)
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)`

Comment: `W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/rafaela/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/rafaela/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'maindeb/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
`

Comment: ps : sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list is empty for me , !!

Comment: "rafela" is the name of  a Linux Mint release, you won't find it in the Canonical repos (who are meant for Ubuntu). Where did you find these URLs?

Comment: i don't know what's the matter besides i don't hve those URLs in ressource.list

Comment: this is what i hve in ressource.list

Comment: `###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse 
###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse `

Comment: `###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
 `

Comment: `###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise maindeb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty  contrib `

Answer (score 0):

When I copy/paste the URL in your comments (I couldn't do that with your initial question, since it's a screenshot) and use it with wget, I get:

```
wget http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/rafaela/partner/binary-amd64/Packages
--2017-07-07 09:56:29--  http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/rafaela/partner/bi%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bnary-amd64/Packages
Resolving archive.canonical.com (archive.canonical.com)... 2001:67c:1360:8c01::16, 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b, 91.189.92.150, ...
Connecting to archive.canonical.com (archive.canonical.com)|2001:67c:1360:8c01::16|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-07-07 09:56:29 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

If you wonder what `%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B` are doing in the URL, they are the bytes of the UTF-8 encodings of two special characters: `U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER` and `U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE`. These characters are really in your post/comment... here the source of the SE page I'm reading:

```
Failed to fetch http:&#47;&#47;archive.canonical.com&#47;ubuntu&#47;dists&#47;rafaela&#47;partner&#47;bi&zwnj;&#8203;nary-amd64&#47;Packages
```

So the question is: did you copy/paste these URLs from a Word document? If so copy them to something that only accepts ASCII (a really basic editor) and clean the mess.

Comment: icopy and pasted it from the  terminal

Comment: So you entered the whole URLin the terminal  by typing it initially? (because I I copy your URL to my terminal, the special characters don't show... it's only `wget` that reports them. So they can be there... Did you try to use these URLs with wget?

Comment: with  ` wget http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/rafaela/partner/binary-i386/Packages ` and `wget http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/rafaela/partner/binary-amd64/Packages`   i get : HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found

Comment: with the otther URLs it fine `Saving to: ‘index.html.1’
100%[======================================>] 67,366       189KB/s   in 0.3s   
2017-07-07 10:57:34 (189 KB/s) - ‘index.html.1’ saved [67366/67366]`